# Find contour within a contour

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

[image]

[image]

I need to detect the letter inside a target. I am able to isolate the target form rest of the image. I am also able to find the outer contour but I am unable to detect the alphabets inside. Is there some other way to detect the alphabet?

Comment: Do you want to detect the letter only if it is inside the red shape ? If not, why don't you detect the yellow shape exactly the same way you detected the red one ?

Comment: yeah, I need to detect the letter only if it's inside the target.

Answer (score 1):

As we all know `Yellow = Green + Red`, while there are two main color: red and yellow, so maybe green channel is a good choice.

Then split the image, I get this:

[image]

So,  `findContour` of `Yellow` with `Red` background in the `Green` channel.

Answer (score 0):

A quick'n'dirty way is to detect both the red star and the yellow letter and check that there is a significant overlap between their bounding boxes.

A more rigorous approach is by applying the point-in-polygon test to any point of the letter wrt the start outline.